# No access to nodes when starting tunslip6 from eclipse

Tags: eclipse, contiki

I have a Java app which connects to my network. I am trying to send a message back to a node in my network (to establish a session key), but when tunslip6 is started by a thread in the Java app, no messages can be sent to the network (tested with ping6).

**What works**:

Starting tunslip6 via command line and pinging nodes via command line:

```
sudo ../../contiki/tools/tunslip6 -s /dev/ttyUSB0 aaaa::1/64 -v5
********SLIP started on ``/dev/ttyUSB0''
opened tun device ``/dev/tun0''
ifconfig tun0 inet `hostname` mtu 1500 up
ifconfig tun0 add aaaa::1/64
ifconfig tun0 add fe80::0:0:0:1/64
ifconfig tun0

tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet addr:127.0.1.1  P-t-P:127.0.1.1  Mask:255.255.255.255
          inet6 addr: aaaa::1/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::8c0d:d6ad:7ead:ef16/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: fe80::1/64 Scope:Link
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:500 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

*** Address:aaaa::1 => aaaa:0000:0000:0000
Got configuration message of type P
Setting prefix aaaa::
Server IPv6 addresses:
 aaaa::212:4b00:615:a4a4
 fe80::212:4b00:615:a4a4
```

Then I can ping aaaa::212:4b00:615:a4a4 and access the neighbor list in the browser.

**What doesn't work**:

Spawning a thread (withing the Java project) which starts tunslip6 succeeds:

```
ifconfig tun0 inet `hostname` mtu 1500 up
ifconfig tun0 add aaaa:1/64
ifconfig tun0 add fe80::0:0:0:1/64
ifconfig tun0

tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet addr:127.0.1.1  P-t-P:127.0.1.1  Mask:255.255.255.255
          inet6 addr: fe80::1/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: fe80::e831:a2b0:1f6b:e49a/64 Scope:Link
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:500 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

Packet from TUN of length 48 - write SLIP
0000 60 00 00 00 00 08 3a ff fe 80 00 00 00 00 00 00 e8 31 a2 b0 1f 6b e4 9a ff 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 85 00 ee 4e 00 00 00 00

Got configuration message of type P

Setting prefix ::

Server IPv6 addresses:

 ::212:4b00:615:a4a4

 fe80::212:4b00:615:a4a4
```

but then it is impossible to ping the border router (under ::212:4b00:615:a4a4) or otherwise send messages to the network.

**Suspicions**:

- I doubt it is something with permissions. ping6 says "Network unreachable" and not something about permissions.
- Something does not work with setting the prefix. The tunslip-output differs for the prefix, even though the command (`./tunslip6 -s /dev/ttyUSB0 aaaa:1/64 -v5`) is the same.
- Could it be that eclipse does something it shouldn't?

Comment: `aaaa:1/64` - you forgot the second column.

Comment: Please let us know if this is resolved.

Comment: Sorry, was gone over the weekend. Good catch, I would have looked a long time for that... This does help, but not solve the issue completely. The prefix gets set properly (server address matches with the working one). New issue: ping6 says `sendmsg: Network unreachable` (instead of `network unreachable`)

Comment: Can you ping `aaaa::1`? Maybe the interface is not up.

Comment: Great hint, thanks! Pinging `aaaa::anything` kills tunslip on the first ping packet (but why?), now suddenly even with the normal console. Using a different prefix (eg. `fd00::1/64`) makes both versions work. Now everything seems to work as intended. Thanks a lot!